# For given operators $a$ and $b$, find all operators satisfying in $\|a-bx\|\leq 1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and consider operators $a$ and $b$ on $H$. 
I am looking forward to any approach that leads me to formulate operators $ x$, in terms of $a$ and $b$, satisfying in the inequality $\|a-bx\|\leq1$.

Comment: Without more information about $a,b$ this is hard to answer. For a start, you could consider the cases $b=0$  or $b$ invertible.